# Wifi says it's connected but it isn't.

Tags: wireless, nvidia

I made a big mistake when trying to help somebody on this site. Someone had a question, and I was working with and hdmi cable and installing the most current nvidia at the same time. My goal was to improve the resolution so that when you plugged in the cable you could see the entire menu and check the setting that you needed.

These are the suggestions I was following:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Since I cannot look it up in the history I don't remember if that was the exact command but the last two words were. Then I did this:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

And that is where I ran into trouble. 
When I plugged in the cable, the monitor went black. I unplugged it and it remained black. I tried to log out with ctrl+alt+del, but I still couldn't see anything. I did a hard shut down. I had to reinstall the OS after that, and now the wifi is not working. The interesting thing about it is it says it's connected. It shows a symbol of a a computer, not the wifi symbol that you usually see. I am using 15.10. Thank you for all of your assistance in advance, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment, but if you did a reinstall it is unlikely anything you did with the driver is affecting you now (unless you somehow produced a hardware problem).  However, my enthusiest-level understanding of how hardware works makes me think it unlikely that anything you were doing with your HDMI port would have affected your Wifi without damaging a lot more than the Wifi... and indeed the likelihood of any harms seems pretty low.  If you are reinstalling, you probably are reinstalling a different version or are downloading newer/updated packages than you had present on your system before.

On the basis of that conclusion, I'd say that you are best of debugging and treating your wifi issue as separate from any of your pre-re-install activities.  Do you know what type of chipset your wifi is using?  Are you sure you have the support packages installed?  Have you gone through the steps here: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting.html ?